# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Driver when upgrading from java 7 to java 11 in sbt 0.13.18 project

Tags: java, scala, sbt, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to update my sbt project from java 7 to java 11. I am using sbt 0.13.18 and scala 2.11.12. The code compiles but when starting the project i encounter the following error.

```
[ERROR] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Driver
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
[ERROR]     at ch.epfl.gsn.Main.loadContainerConfig(Main.java:312)
```

The code snippet below provides the line where the error occurs:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
```

sbt show runtime:fullClasspath yields all necessary Dependencies so this should not be the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you're using a modular project, and it doesn't require module `java.sql`.

Comment: No, since the project is from back then, it doesn't use JPMS.

Comment: I'm wondering if Scala itself somehow relies on the module system on Java 9+, but I haven't touched Scala in a few years, so I'm not sure. The module system is the only reason I can think of why you'd get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Driver` (specifically, that module `java.sql` is not on the module path).

Comment: are you just upgrading from java 7 to 11? have you tried first upgrade to java 8? maybe upgrade to scala 2.12.x? only with that message is hard to guess the root cause. could you share your `build.sbt`? is it possible to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have updates from 7 to 8 before and that worked. Upgrading to scala 2.12.x was the key. Thanks